# Closing main window is not allowed

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp

I'm developing an UWP app that surrpots multiple windows like Microsoft Edge or Sticky Notes.

I succeeded to close child window by caling `Window.Current.Close()`, but cannot close main window, or the base window of child windows.

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in MyApp.exe
WinRT information: Closing main window is not allowed.
```

On the other hand, we can run Microsoft Edge windows and close them regardless of the order.

Is there any way to close main window or change parent-child relationship of windows?

Comment: The main window is special: Closing it exits the application. If that's what you want to do, then use Application.Exit.

Answer (score 1):

Execute `ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryConsolidateAsync()` in main window to close it properly as if you have closed it by clicking close button in title bar. If your app has only one window per instance you should prefer this over `Application.Exit()` as this method suspends the app while `Application.Exit()` closes app abruptly. Also closing app by this method your app's previous position and size is remembered unlike for `Application.Exit()`.